# Optimize a bit decoding operation in C

Tags: c, performance, bit-manipulation

I have an unsigned 32 bit integer encoded in the following way:

- the first 6 bits define the `opcode`
- next 8 bits define a `register`
- next 18 bits are a two's complement signed integer `value`.

I am currently decoding this number (uint32_t inst) using:

```
const uint32_t opcode = ((inst >> 26) & 0x3F);
const uint32_t r1 = (inst >> 18) & 0xFF;
const int32_t value = ((inst >> 17) & 0x01) ? -(131072 - (inst & 0x1FFFF)) : (inst & 0x1FFFF);
```

I can measure a significant overhead while decoding the value and I am quite sure it is due to the ternary operator (essentially an if statment) used to compare the sign an perform the negative operation.

Is there a way to perform value decoding in a faster way?

Comment: Isn't that 40 bits? (6 + 8 + 1 + 25)

Comment: @WeatherVane: The last is 17 bits.

Comment: Some compilers provide builtins for special operations. And some platforms provide intrinsic function for special instructions, e.g. sign-extend or bitfield extract (which the first two at least might evaluate to with a good optimising compiler). But your approach is basically correct. How does the Assembler code look like?

Comment: Sorry just fixed, value is 17 bits.

Comment: Ah, there @WeatherVane got the `25`:-) I tend to ignore text and look at the code.

Comment: @Olaf Go directly to the source (pun intended).

Comment: The traditional way to do this would be to exploit arithmetic rights shifts with `(int32_t) (inst << 14) >> 14`. Or bias-and-subtract  `(inst & 0x3FFFF ^ 0x20000) - 0x20000` if worried about the undefined behavior of arithmetic right shifts.

Comment: @user3528438: 14 I believe. That should bring the sign of the 18-bit two's complement integer field at the bottom up as the sign of the 32-bit field while shifting out the 6+8=14 bits of opcode/register fields.

Comment: why use sign-magnitude? use 2's complement and now there's no sign bit needed. Just a simple sign-extension is enough to get the value

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, look at his decoding -- he *is* using two's complement.

Comment: @JohnBollinger in that case he has converted it the "wrong" way. A simple shift left then right whould work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your expression is more complicated than it needs to be, especially in needlessly involving the ternary operator.  The following expression computes the same results for all inputs without involving the ternary operator.<sup>*</sup>  It is a good candidate for a replacement, but as with any optimization problem, it is essential to test:

```
const int32_t value = (int32_t)(inst & 0x1FFFF) - (int32_t)(inst & 0x20000);
```

Or this variation on @doynax's suggestion along similar lines might be more optimizer-friendly:

```
const int32_t value = (int32_t)(inst & 0x3FFFF ^ 0x20000) - (int32_t)0x20000;
```

In each case, the casts avoid implementation-defined behavior; on many architectures they would be no-ops as far as the machine code is concerned.  On those architectures, these expressions involve fewer operations in all cases than does yours, not to mention being unconditional.

Competitive alternatives involving shifting may also optimize well, but all such alternatives necessarily rely on implementation-defined behavior because of integer overflow of a left shift, a negative integer being the left-hand operand of a right shift, and / or converting an out-of-range value to a signed integer type.  You will have to determine for yourself whether constitutes a problem.

<sup>*</sup> *as compiled by GCC 4.4.7 for x86_64.  The original expression invokes implementation-defined behavior for some inputs, so on other implementations the two expressions might compute different values for those inputs.*

Comment: That subtraction doesn't full optimize away :(.  It's easiest to see with gcc targeting ARM, which has [signed and unsigned bitfield-extract instructions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001m/QRC0001_UAL.pdf) (which take two immediate operands as well as the src and dest registers).  [gcc 4.8 uses that for `r1`, and a shift for the opcode](https://godbolt.org/g/8g0O2A), but uses an unsigned extract and then AND / SUB for the `value`.  @Anatoly's version, and a version with signed vs. unsigned struct bitfields, make ideal code.

Comment: @PeterCordes, it depends on your definition of "ideal".  Anatoly's inherently relies on implementation-defined behavior, as he acknowledges.  This one does not.  Whether that matters to the OP is unclear, but certainly he should take my advice to employ performance testing in his evaluation of alternatives.

Comment: I meant "ideal code" as in "optimal asm code".  i.e. the compiler "understands" that it just needs to sign-extend the bit-field into an `int32_t`.  @doynax's `(inst & 0x3FFFF ^ 0x20000) - 0x20000` fits the bill, for gcc 4.8 at least.  I'd suggest updating your answer to use that:  [It compiles to optimal code for ARM and x86](https://godbolt.org/g/fuvLGO), but unlike all the other suggestions that make good code, has no undefined or implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: @PeterCordes, fair enough, I have added a version of doynax's approach.  Note that it requires some casts (which I added) to avoid implementation defined behavior for some inputs, in the form of converting an out-of-range value to signed integer type.  The subtraction must be performed with signed operands (after the usual arithmetic conversions) to produce a signed result.

Comment: The mask needs to include the sign-bit.  `0x3...` not `0x1...`.  I was thinking for a while that your safety-casts defeated the optimizer, but no, your version of it was just computing something different.  With 0x3... it compiles to what we want: https://godbolt.org/g/xMN8og

Comment: Can you explain exactly where the unsafe conversion happens, and why?  Is it because we're assigning the result of the expression to an `int32_t`?  (and that's the same as a `return` in a function returning `int32_t`, right?)  Why don't you need a `0x3FFFFU` unsigned constant, to keep the operands inside the `()` unsigned?  Or does the `(int32_t)` cast outside the parens keep the assignment type from being applied inside the parens?  I should just look this up myself >.<

Comment: @PeterCordes, without any casts, all operands and results on the right-hand side of the assignment, including the result of the subtraction, have type `uint32_t` (unless `int` were wider than 32 bits).  In that case, the only way the implicit conversion in the assignment to `value` could ever yield a negative result is by relying on implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So the version without casts did unsigned subtraction with wraparound, and then assigned that to a signed int.  Yeah, that only works on 2's complement, but the C standard also allows 1's complement and sign/magnitude.  With the casts, your version will work on those, too.  Nice catch!

Answer (score 3):

A standard (even though non-portable) practice is a left-shift followed by an arithmetic right-shift:

```
const int32_t temp = inst << 14; // "shift out" the 14 unneeded bits
const int32_t value = temp >> 14; // shift the number back; sign-extend
```

This involves a conversion from `uint32_t` to `int32_t` and a right-shift of a possibly negative `int32_t`; both operations are implementation-defined, i.e. unportable (work on 2's complement systems; pretty much guaranteed to work on any architecture). If you want to gain the best performance and willing to rely on implementation-defined behavior, you can use this code.

As a single expression:

```
const int32_t value = (int32_t)(inst << 14) >> 14;
```

Note: the following looks cleaner, will also typically work, but involves *undefined* behavior (signed integer overflow):

```
const int32_t value = (int32_t)inst << 14 >> 14;
```

Don't use it! (even though you probably won't receive any warning or error about it).

Comment: There are 17 value bits and 1 sign bit, so doesn't this approach require 14-bit shifts rather than 15-bit?

Comment: it should be `(int32_t)temp << 18 >> 18;`

Comment: Yes, should shift by 14 bits, not 15. Not 18 either.

Answer (score 2):

For **ideal compiler output with no implementation-defined or undefined behaviour**, use @doynax's 2's complement decoding expression:

```
value = (int32_t)((inst & 0x3FFFF) ^ 0x20000) - (int32_t)0x20000;
```

The casts make sure we're doing signed subtraction, rather than unsigned with wraparound and then assigning that bit-pattern to a signed integer.

This compiles to optimal asm on ARM, where gcc uses `sbfx  r1, r1, #0, #18` [(signed bitfield-extract)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001m/QRC0001_UAL.pdf) to sign-extend bits [17:0] into a full `int32_t` register.  On x86, it uses `shl` by 14 and `sar` by 14 (arithmetic shift) to do the same thing.  This is a clear sign that gcc recognizes the 2's complement pattern and uses whatever is most optimal on the target machine to sign-extend the bitfield.

There isn't a portable way to make sure bitfields are ordered the way you want them.  gcc appears to order bitfields from LSB to MSB for little-endian targets, but MSB to LSB for big-endian targets.  You can use an `#if` to get identical asm output for ARM with/without `-mbig-endian`, just like the other methods, [but there's no guarantee that other compilers work the same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field).

If gcc/clang didn't see through the xor and sub, it would be worth considering the `<<14` / `>>14` implementation which hand-holds the compiler towards doing it that way.  Or considering the signed/unsigned bitfield approach with an `#if`.

But since we can get ideal asm from gcc/clang with fully safe and portable code, we should just do that.

See the code on the [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang371,options:%27-xc+--std%3Dgnu99+-O3+++-Wall+-Wextra+-fverbose-asm+-march%3Dhaswell%27,sourcez:PTAEGIEsDsGMBsCuATApqAPAZwC7JjgHQAWAfAFDk4CeADqmgGaiLRaQDm0DoBLBAZgBMAfRwBuKnQapmfQaImVyuAE6JYOUGlgB7NKADe5UKBCt2XHrGIBDVaF209aADShVARkmmLnbsi80FpOLqjuXj5BOMJioAButkiokgC%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%2BFYgR8F4Lzwe4oSji8KKSOARRkrJUnyQJaloBpESeMpUSWAEAkwYgqBwYhC6OpAzCgOQ6SUHwHDwLo2RJCIMBiBcIiklUIhWrQvT7uwABeqC6IwL5qBoWgwMcIEZD2FL4EqFKTDGqDHKcji0EqVSQLFoC2FcZTkPEuiQIEOijmIYwTKo1BhbQiWJslj5agAVHhWCIPAODuIgChxKlOAgWmphDSNOCNKQRnoPuL4vtNoCkKQoBCCis0AGSgOCAAeAi1ul4ELaNy1eLuoCbWwWg7aACFHSdp21rWUQ3UtpA2Wtj1Pbg227Z4ADsH1neCnizbGoCNC%2BngCJ44IQ0IiOPVtx1nZ433fSBs0vNjz2gLjp34wTV2pLiYCCs6yDAMN2T8icIQlZAZUVVVNV1Q1fXNSzia2JoIgAFa6MQ0DdUmWhNQYg0FYt42TSlz2zcY83K7dK3OKOD0bVtr37dD52Xb9Ov/fd63G%2BD8Fm99lvDbrgOG09MSKCBINaBTVOE1jHuxDNPvk59EKQuCRNpHToCbHyrCZgEwBc7xXJyjgiqQBSzRPlZ2SoHY8TZ4gqiqQ4TnOtwWBYK6vS4BG8CgDUIoFbwaCTCFtX1Y1qBhCIQhYCIoa0CIMbUBMp2y71CvoErLtjfwwTBymM1zR4VvLat7t23tB1h2dF1XdrC93Z4hu7%2B9B9fT912bwDSS2RfZMUxdBOgAAeuHkdR1jZ0R5CGOdwABSUsTiiX0M5SAsAs4UhJjA0G2RdDnAgmgGczBBTCwVJobOlJeQQXkncaaqBbCBHiiwdgdFJKWR4FcBUtB7AVDaJVZhpJLLKnHFoFioAGGPFalSPktgCFWQIN3AWs8B5DxHiILijA%2B6khwFgaeyZZ6gHnirJenspoa3Xn9Le%2BsDDrVDibfer8LZ31PqQG2pNQavSvhTJ2FjFrLTdrbZeXtQ5mPfl/f%2BP9ZqNFJlomavjI5ALuJOVQ053Bug3gARwmkNUAPpoCNFoH8TO2RIyCXyIUYooBSjlF6GwxAYYcpsDEb3fuwlkBKKSiovuBt1GjVVu47RuBNZ6VwUYTRK8PS6EjEhOp6tUzVKwEhVIVIwwPUMKvUA7lTBON1tvfc2JaCEFGb8AxKRFnW3PissM6zck1MIJEHZLjH5A1WYcjiWBCCAyAVkCJUSci9BaI6GclJU6Rj7JnMpucCj50LrYYuFQHDkNegXZUzpKqEnOBqJUsAPCcAeByYgzkcAVMFmgGR9hgoTF5PAagHBlHywaYrP6LSgmrw6SfZxestRGN3qba%2BR9nZ0uscY%2B2jtb6mDVlSLktAHpbQwBgN6UIkJZAAERYDRYwEIlRJUqnQJ4KEkluAyECCxWutLXYXIesyKZdjxWuVpncLiGoeGqB8t8yqIxQHS2GCTA42wWGcUQNkEWyZ7DoAbvAJuwZUCYokYPYepFR7MkgIkaKJKsVzwpT0xQ1LdH32WcDJlpjPqsrOVYvZNiXpcuvo40wegyYTVaVobgHAs7xCBkbMmdiobX1hsfDeljXGmCRpW6tc83qo3RpjAJnjPr%2B0ujTcgQAAA%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3), for versions from most of the answers.  You can look at asm output for x86, ARM, ARM64, or PowerPC.

```
// have to put the results somewhere, so the function doesn't optimize away
struct decode {
  //unsigned char opcode, r1;
  unsigned int opcode, r1;
  int32_t value;
};
// in real code you might return the struct by value, but there's less ABI variation when looking at the ASM this way (some would pack the struct into registers)

void decode_two_comp_doynax(struct decode *result, uint32_t inst) {
  result->opcode = ((inst >> 26) & 0x3F);
  result->r1 = (inst >> 18) & 0xFF;
  result->value = ((inst & 0x3FFFF) ^ 0x20000) - 0x20000;
}

# clang 3.7.1 -O3 -march=haswell   (enables BMI1 bextr)
    mov     eax, esi
    shr     eax, 26                     # grab the top 6 bits with a shift
    mov     dword ptr [rdi], eax
    mov     eax, 2066          # (0x812)# only AMD provides bextr r32, r32, imm.  Intel has to set up the constant separately
    bextr   eax, esi, eax               # extract the middle bitfield
    mov     dword ptr [rdi + 4], eax
    shl     esi, 14                     # <<14
    sar     esi, 14                     # >>14 (arithmetic shift)
    mov     dword ptr [rdi + 8], esi
    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using bit-fields to simplify your code.

```
typedef struct inst_type {
#ifdef MY_MACHINE_NEEDS_THIS
    uint32_t opcode :  6;
    uint32_t r1     :  8;
    int32_t  value  : 18;
#else
    int32_t  value  : 18;
    uint32_t r1     :  8;
    uint32_t opcode :  6;
#endif
} inst_type;

const uint32_t opcode = inst.opcode;
const uint32_t r1 = inst.r1;
const int32_t value = inst.value;
```

Direct bit manipulation often performs better, but not always. Using John Bollinger's answer as a baseline, the above structure results in one fewer instruction to extract the three values of interest on GCC (but fewer instructions does not necessarily mean faster).

Comment: The condition for ordering is not "big-endian", though endianness is probably a good guess. See e.g. BITS_BIG_ENDIAN [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Storage-Layout.html).

Comment: @anatolyg: [`BITS_BIG_ENDIAN` is internal to gcc and doesn't affect bitfield layout.  It tells gcc how to use a machine's bitfield instructions, if it has them.](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2004-09/msg00635.html).  It turns out that `#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__` is the correct condition for gcc: with that, [you get the same code on ARM with/without `-mbig-endian`](https://godbolt.org/g/3izdaW).  I guess gcc lays out bitfields in an order than depends on machine endianness.  It's not safe to assume all other compilers do the same, though.

Comment: Note that it is implementation defined whether plain `int` bit-fields are signed or unsigned.  In theory, you might need `signed int value : 18;` (assuming `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT >= 18`).  It is not clear that `int32_t` will be explicitly signed.  It's distinctly an edge case, but then almost everything to do with bit-fields is an edge case.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I don't deny using bit-fields may rely on implementation defined behavior, but it is a lot easier to understand the intention of the code than to do mental calculations to figure out the intention of shifts and masks.

Answer (score 0):

```
const uint32_t opcode = ((inst >> 26) & 0x3F);
const uint32_t r1 = (inst >> 18) & 0xFF;
const uint32_t negative = ((inst >> 17) & 0x01);
const int32_t value =  -(negative * 131072 - (inst & 0x1FFFF));
```

when `negative` is 1 `-(131072 - (inst & 0x1FFFF))` and for 0: `-(0 - (inst & 0x1FFFF))` which is equal to `inst & 0x1FFFF`.